# Listview not updating in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am working on an android project I have a search field in activity when I search something. I am sending search keyword to the fragment through bundle when I refresh the list updated but list view showing previous data. I used all possible solutions but the result keeps on showing the same result. I got stuck in my code. but when list view and edit text on the same activity it works fine. The problem occurs when I filter keyword from activity to fragment and then update the list.

here is my adapter Class.

```
package com.Celeritas.JSBank.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.telephony.VisualVoicemailService;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.Celeritas.JSBank.ListViewModels.OnlineModel;
import com.Celeritas.JSBank.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by anas on 10/27/2017.
 */
public class OnlineCourseAvailableAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OnlineModel> {

    List<OnlineModel> value;
    List<OnlineModel> arraylist;
    private ViewHolder holder;

    public OnlineCourseAvailableAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<OnlineModel> value) {
        super(context, resource, value);
        this.value = value;
        arraylist = new ArrayList<OnlineModel>();
        arraylist.addAll(value);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.online_course_available_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv_day.setText(value.get(position).getDay());
        holder.tv_date.setText(value.get(position).getMonthyear());
        holder.tv_title.setText(value.get(position).getTitle_tv());
        holder.tv_completed.setText(value.get(position).getCompleted_onOtv());
        holder.target.setText(value.get(position).getTargetAudience());

        return convertView;

    }

    public List<OnlineModel> filter1(String charText) {

        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

        value.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            value.addAll(arraylist);

        } else {
            for (OnlineModel onlineModel : arraylist) {
                if (charText.length() != 0 && onlineModel.getTitle_tv().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    value.add(onlineModel);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return value;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView tv_day;
        TextView tv_date;
        TextView tv_title;
        TextView tv_completed;
        TextView target;
        ImageView arrow;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            tv_day = view.findViewById(R.id.date_day);
            tv_date = view.findViewById(R.id.date_monthyear);
            tv_title = view.findViewById(R.id.title_tv);
            tv_completed = view.findViewById(R.id.completed_on_tv);
            target = view.findViewById(R.id.target);
            arrow = view.findViewById(R.id.arrow);

        }
    }

}
```

And Here I am updating the adapter

```
package com.Celeritas.JSBank.Fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.Celeritas.JSBank.Activities.CourseDiscription;
import com.Celeritas.JSBank.Adapter.OnlineCourseAvailableAdapter;
import com.Celeritas.JSBank.ListViewModels.OnlineModel;
import com.Celeritas.JSBank.Models.DesignationModel;
import com.Celeritas.JSBank.Models.OnlineCourseModel;
import com.Celeritas.JSBank.Models.TeachersModel;
import com.Celeritas.JSBank.R;
import com.Celeritas.JSBank.Storage.Data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OnlineAvailableFragment extends Fragment {

    private List<OnlineModel> list  = new ArrayList<>();
    private OnlineCourseAvailableAdapter adapter;
    private ListView lv;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_online_available, container, false);

        lv = view.findViewById(R.id.listview_available);



        LoadData(view);
/*        if (Data.keyword.length() !=0){
            adapter = new OnlineCourseAvailableAdapter(getActivity(),
                    R.layout.fragment_online_available, list);
            adapter.filter("Kyc");
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.invalidateViews();
        }*/



        return view;
    }

    private void LoadData(View view) {

        final List<OnlineCourseModel> tem = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i= 0; i< Data.onlineCourseModelList.size();i++){
            String startDate =  Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getStartdate();
            String[] parts = startDate.split("-", 0);
            String date = parts[0];
            String month = parts[1];
            String year = parts[2];

            if (Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("upcoming")){
                String TargetAudienc = convertToCommaDelimited(Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getDesignationModels());
                if (TargetAudienc.length() == 0){
                    TargetAudienc = "ALL";
                }
                list.add(new OnlineModel(date, month+"-"+year, Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getFullname(),
                        "End on: "+Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getEnddate(),"Target Audience: "+ TargetAudienc));

                tem.add(new OnlineCourseModel(Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getFullname(),Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getShortname(),
                        Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getSummary(),Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getStartdate(),Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getEnddate(),
                        Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getScormlink(),Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getKey(),Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getTrainingarea(),
                        Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getCategoryid(),Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getEnrolldate(),Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getCompletiondate(),
                        Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getCourseid(),Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getGradeModelses(),Data.onlineCourseModelList.get(i).getDesignationModels()));

            }
        }

        adapter = new OnlineCourseAvailableAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.fragment_online_available, list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null) {
            String keyword = getArguments().getString("keyword");
            if (keyword != null && !keyword.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                adapter.filter1("Kyc");
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                lv.invalidateViews();
            }
        }
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CourseDiscription.class);
                Data.StartDate = tem.get(i).getStartdate();
                Data.EndDate = tem.get(i).getEnddate();
                Data.TargetAudeince = tem.get(i).getDesignationModels();
                Data.Course = tem.get(i).getFullname();
                Data.Category = tem.get(i).getCategoryid();
                Data.CourseId = tem.get(i).getCourseid();
                Data.Discription = Data.html2text(tem.get(i).getSummary());
                Data.ScormLink = tem.get(i).getScormlink();
                Data.Key = tem.get(i).getKey();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public static OnlineAvailableFragment newInstance() {
        return new OnlineAvailableFragment();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post code how you send data to fragment ?

Comment: You already notify adapter inside filter1 so no need to write this code  lv.setAdapter(adapter); lv.invalidateViews(); after apply filter list.

Comment: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction FT = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        OnlineAvailableFragment mfc = new OnlineAvailableFragment();
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putString("keyword", s.toString().trim());
                        mfc.setArguments(b);
                        FT.replace(R.id.main_container, mfc);
                        FT.commit();